# validate html form using java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am new to js [ Client side scripting ]

I worked on php earlier Now I think i need to use js for my application, here is a tiny code for that .

```
<form name = "Purchase" action = "purchase.php" method = "POST">
<select name = "pname">
<option value = "p1"> p1 </option>
<option value = "p2"> p2 </option>
<input type = "number" name = "price" required></input>
<input type = "number" name = "Total" required></input>
<input type = "submit" name = "NewPurchase" Value = "Add">
</form>
```

I would like to validate that all the values are set or not mainly **drop down** in the form if it is not selected then alert message should display saying that value is not selected I have modified the same file as show below but is not working.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function validateForm(objForm)
{
    var returnStatus = 1;
    if (objForm.Make.selectedIndex == 0) 
    {
        alert("Please select a all select options");
        returnStatus = 0;
    };
    if (returnStatus) 
    {
        objForm.submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

modified input submit tag too as

```
<input type = "submit" name = "NewPurchase" Value = "Add" onClick="validateForm(document.testform)">
```

Presently I am validating all the values using php in the next page ["purchase.php"] using isset()

Please let me know how to use the same in js .

Comment: Have a look into this also, JQuery Validate Plugin
http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: Why not just rely on HTML5  client side validation?

Comment: @EJTH : Yeah we can do that but we may not sure which version client may use , if it is HTML4 means it would be prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I would not recommend alerts(). Sure they are nice and fullfill their duty, yet they also block the rest of the browser pretty much.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <Script>
            function validateForm(e){
                var tStatus = 1;

                if (e){
                    var tE = e.parentNode; //Getting the form container.
                    var tL = document.querySelectorAll('[required]'); //Get required elements;

                    for(var i=0, j=tL.length;i<j;i++){
                        tL[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'; //Reseting our error marks.

                        if (tL[i].tagName === 'SELECT' && tL[i].selectedIndex === 0){
                            //For dropdowns, we check if not the first option is selected
                            var tStatus = 0;
                            tL[i].style.backgroundColor = 'crimson';
                            //alert('..') //Can put alerts instead, but alerts are rarely a good option
                        }
                        else if (tL[i].tagName === 'INPUT' && tL[i].type == 'number' && (tL[i].value.trim() === '' || isNaN(tL[i].value))){
                            //For number input, we check if a value is entered which is a number.
                            var tStatus = 0;
                            tL[i].style.backgroundColor = 'crimson';
                            //alert('..') //Can put alerts instead, but alerts are rarely a good option
                        }
                        else if (tL[i].tagName === 'INPUT' && tL[i].type == 'text' && tL[i].value.trim() === ''){
                            //For input, we check if any text is entered which is not only whitespaces.
                            var tStatus = 0;
                            tL[i].style.backgroundColor = 'crimson';
                            //alert('..') //Can put alerts instead, but alerts are rarely a good option
                        };
                    };
                };

                //Proceed how ever you want with your status [0|1]
                return (tStatus === 1);
            };
        </Script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name = "Purchase" action = "purchase.php" method = "POST">
            <select name = "pname" required>
                <option value = "p1"> p1 </option>
                <option value = "p2"> p2 </option>
            </select> <!-- Close the select? -->

            <input type = "text" name = "text" required></input>
            <input type = "number" name = "Total" required></input>
            <input type = "number" name = "Total" required></input>
            <input type = "submit" name = "NewPurchase" Value = "Add" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that , In validateform function, can we make SELECT tag condition using value insted of "first option is selected" ?

Comment: Sure, this is how you get the value: tL[i].options[tL[i].selectedIndex].value

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to close select so your select would be like:

```
<select name = "pname" id="pname">
 <option value = "p1"> p1 </option>
 <option value = "p2"> p2 </option>
</select>
```

assign id to each of your input field;

remove `;` in your js code

if check it in your js function use, document.getElementById("id_of_input");

```
if (value==""){
       alert("fill abc field"); 
       return false;
  }
```

similarly, check all of them

instead of onclick Event add an event to the form

```
 onsubmit="return  validateForm();"
```

return true in your js function at the end, if any of the input gets  failed, it will return false so the form won't be submitted.

You can use `isset()` function but that is pointless here since you are doing client side validation..

you can user required="required" , that is in html5 and won't let user to submit the form without add some value in the field.

Comment: OP is also asking about a `isset()` in PHP, can you extend ?

Comment: @Random changed my answer